# Why does node.js app CSS load in my IDE but not on a localhost?

Tags: html, css, path, localhost, static-resource

I am making a nodejs application using LightTable, and the css seems to be loading fine when I indicate a relative path to the file in my `<link href="">` tag. When I run `node index.js`, however, the server starts up and the page loads fine, but I get a console error and my own 404 saying the CSS file could not be found at the path specified. I tried using Heroku's `Foreman Start` as well, but no dice. Here is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Home
        </title>
        <link href="../../styles/master.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
...
```

Here is my directory tree structure:

```
.
├── Procfile
├── README.md
├── index.js
├── package.json
├── resources
│   └── images
│       └── tokyo.jpg
├── styles
│   └── master.css
└── views
    ├── get
    │   ├── home.html
    │   └── posts.html
    └── post
        └── new.html
```

**EDIT:** after finding the answer to the question, the below information became relevant. I have commented out the new code that makes the CSS and background image load as desired.

Here is my routing and server code. I am not using Express, on purpose:

```
    // routes
    var homeREGEX = new RegExp('^/?$');
    var newREGEX = new RegExp('^/posts/new/?$');
    var postsREGEX = new RegExp('^/posts/?$');
 // var cssREGEX = new RegExp('^/styles/master.css/?$');             <--| static resources also
 // var tokyoREGEX = new RegExp('^/resources/images/tokyo.jpg/?$');  <--| need routes. 

    // server
    var server = http.createServer(function(request, response){
      var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;

      if (homeREGEX.test(pathname)) {
        renderHome(request, response);

      } else if (newREGEX.test(pathname)) {
        renderPostForm(request, response);
      } else if (postsREGEX.test(pathname)) {
        addNewPost(request, response);
   // } else if (cssREGEX.test(pathname)) {           <--| and they need to get
   //   sendCSS(request, response);                   <--| served individually as
   // } else if (tokyoREGEX.test(pathname)) {         <--| they are requested
   //   sendTokyo(request, response);
      } else {
        error404(request, response);
      }
    });
```

Comment: What's the URL you see in your browser when you're looking at the page and it doesn't work?

Comment: localhost:3000, but if I navigate over to localhost:3000/styles/master.css, I get a 404 not found, error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the url you use in your browser when viewing the page ? My guess is that is does not contains the `views/get` part, which means that you don't need the `..\..` in your link href attributes.

Also, make sure your are actually serving these static files (it seems you're not). If you're using express (with nodejs ) for example, you'll need something like this :

```
app.use(express.static('resources'));
app.use(express.static('style'));
```

See [`express.static` documentation](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#express.static).

Comment: I've tried removing and adding "../"s in every combination I can think of. Not working yet!

Comment: ok, but please give your url, otherwise there's nothing we can do.

Comment: I posted it above: localhost:3000. In the console it says `x-GET localhost:3000/styles/master.css`, and confirmed a 404 not found error when I navigated there.

Comment: are you sure you're actually serving the file ? see my updated answer.

Comment: This might be my issue, actually. I am not using Express, because I want to understand the internals and then build my way up to the framework. How can I do something like app.use without Express?

Comment: Okay, I figured this out! It was that I didn't have route handler for the path to the css file. I included the necessary details into my server and voila. It worked. I guess that the other technologies that I have been using do all that under the hood, or something. I have accepted your answer, but I would appreciate it if you could update it explaining this fact. It is a beginner error, but easy to fall into nonetheless. I will add my old routing code in an edit to my question too.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try to put the exact path instead of ../../

```
<link href="/Procfile/styles/master.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```